# Computing Fréchet derivatives in the space of continuous bounded functions.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $\mu, \nu$ be two probability measures on the real line. Let $c(x,y)$ be a real function such that the functional below is always well defined. I am interested in the Fréchet partial derivatives of the functional

\begin{equation}
J(\varphi, \psi)=\int_{\mathbb R} \varphi(x) \, d \mu(x)+\int_{\mathbb R} \psi(y) \, d \nu(y) -\int_{\mathbb R \times \mathbb R} e^{{\varphi(x) + \psi(y)- c(x,y)}} d \mu (x) d \nu (y).
\end{equation}

where $(\varphi, \psi)$ live in the space of real bounded continuous functions equipped with the sup norm. How would one compute such derivatives ? I know the definition, but how to determine what bounded linear operator one has to plug in in the limit so it becomes $0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it assuming $(x,y)\mapsto e^{-c(x,y)}$ is integrable with respect to the product measure $\zeta=\mu\times\nu$ (and I guess this is a necessary assumption for $J$ to even make sense, simply by setting $\phi=\psi=0$). Whenever you wish to compute Frechet derivatives of a huge mess, always start by computing the directional (Gateaux) derivatives, because if the Frechet derivative exists, then so does the directional derivative. Conversely, if all directional derivatives exist and are continuous, then the function is Frechet differentiable (this is the analogue of all partial derivatives in $\Bbb{R}^n$ being continuous implies the function itself is differentiable).

Note that the first two terms are define a bounded (because you're integrating bounded functions with respect to finite measures) bilinear functional of $(\phi,\psi)$, hence that part is Frechet differentiable, and there's no issue with that. Let us thus focus our attention on
\begin{align}
H(\phi,\psi):= \int_{X}e^{\phi(x)+\psi(y)-c(x,y)}\,d\zeta(x,y),
\end{align}
where for ease of typing I have set $X=\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\zeta=\mu\times \nu$, the product measure. Let $(\alpha,\beta)\in BC(\Bbb{R})\times BC(\Bbb{R})$. Then the directional derivative at the point $(\phi,\psi)$ along the vector $(\alpha,\beta)$ is
\begin{align}
(D_{(\alpha,\beta)}H)(\phi,\psi)&:=\dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}H\bigg((\phi,\psi)+t(\alpha,\beta)\bigg)\\
&=\dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\int_Xe^{\phi(x)+\psi(y) + t(\alpha(x)+\beta(y))-c(x,y)}\,d\zeta(x,y)\\
&=\int_X [\alpha(x)+\beta(y)]e^{\phi(x)+\psi(y)-c(x,y)}\,d\zeta(x,y).\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Here, I have differentiated under the integral sign, and this is justified since all the functions are bounded functions $\phi,\psi,\alpha,\beta$, and the integrable $e^{-c(\cdot,\cdot)}$ and we're dealing with finite measures. Let us show this is a continuous function of $(\phi,\psi)$. To do this, let $(\xi,\eta)\in BC\times BC$ be a "displacement" vector. Then,
\begin{align}
&\left| (D_{(\alpha,\beta)}H)(\phi+\xi,\psi+\eta) - (D_{(\alpha,\beta)}H)(\phi,\psi)\right|\\
&\leq\int_X\left|\alpha(x)+\beta(y)\right|\left|e^{\phi(x)+\psi(y)-c(x,y)}\right|\cdot
\left|e^{\xi(x)+\eta(y)}-1\right|\,d\zeta(x,y)\\
&\leq \bigg(\left(\lVert \alpha\rVert+\lVert \beta\rVert\right)\cdot e^{\lVert \phi\rVert
+\lVert \psi\rVert}\cdot\int_Xe^{-c(x,y)}\,d\zeta(x,y)\bigg)\cdot \left[e^{\lVert \xi\rVert+\lVert \eta\rVert}-1\right]
\end{align}
Note that the big bracketed term is a finite non-negative constant. As $(\xi,\eta)\to 0$ (where we use one of the obvious product norms), we have $\lVert \xi\rVert+\lVert \eta\rVert\to 0$, and thus the term in square brackets approaches $0$, so the whole RHS approaches $0$. This proves $(\psi,\psi)\mapsto (D_{(\alpha,\beta)}H)(\phi,\psi)$ is continuous. Also, from $(*)$, it's clear we have a continuous linear functional of $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Therefore, $H$ is (continuously) Frechet differentiable, and its Frechet derivative at $(\phi,\psi)$ evaluated on $(\alpha,\beta)$ is related to the directional derivative as follows:
\begin{align}
DH_{(\phi,\psi)}(\alpha,\beta)&=(D_{(\alpha,\beta)}H)(\phi,\psi)\\
&=\int_X [\alpha(x)+\beta(y)]e^{\phi(x)+\psi(y)-c(x,y)}\,d\zeta(x,y).
\end{align}
Finally, recalling that $J$ and $H$ differ by the a bounded bilinear functional (i.e the first two terms), it follows that
\begin{align}
DJ_{(\phi,\psi)}(\alpha,\beta)&=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\alpha(x)\,d\mu(x)+\int_{\Bbb{R}}\beta(y)\,d\nu(y)-DH_{(\phi,\psi)}(\alpha,\beta)\\
&=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\alpha(x)\,d\mu(x)+\int_{\Bbb{R}}\beta(y)\,d\nu(y)-
\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}[\alpha(x)+\beta(y)]e^{\phi(x)+\psi(y)-c(x,y)}\,d\zeta(x,y)
\end{align}
This is the full Frechet-derivative of $J$. The partial derivatives are
\begin{align}
(\partial_1J)_{(\phi,\psi)}(\alpha)&=DJ_{(\phi,\psi)}(\alpha,0)\\
&=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\alpha(x)\,d\mu(x) -\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}\alpha(x)e^{\phi(x)+\psi(y)-c(x,y)}\,d\zeta(x,y),
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(\partial_2J)_{(\phi,\psi)}(\beta)&=DJ_{(\phi,\psi)}(0,\beta)\\
&=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\beta(y)\,d\nu(y) -\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}\beta(y)e^{\phi(x)+\psi(y)-c(x,y)}\,d\zeta(x,y).
\end{align}

---

As a summary, always compute directional derivatives first (if you do not know where to begin) because this reduces your domain to a one-dimensional interval; then afterwards try to argue by continuity that Frechet differentiability follows. In this particular case, the crucial aspect was that the function $\phi\mapsto \exp\circ \phi$ is a continuous mapping from $BC(\Bbb{R})\to BC(\Bbb{R})$. The rest is clear, and it's a matter of being comfortable with the differential calculus (relationship between directional, Frechet and partial derivatives).